# Saving Password with Md5

Tags: java, sql, database, encryption, password-protection

I am using Postgresql,hibernate and Java and I need to store a password. Can someone suggest me how to encrypt the password with md5. Else is there a better way to store secure password in the database

Thanks

Comment: If you obscure a password with MD5 (or other hashing algorithm), it's not possible to get back the original password. However, that may not be necessary - often all you need to do is check whether the password the user entered is the same as the stored one, in which case you can calculate the MD5 (or other hash) of that and see if you get the same as what's stored. But if you want to use the password, for example, to log into a database, then you'll need the original password, and MD5 isn't what you want. (BTW MD5 is considered broken, so best to choose another algorithm!)

Comment: You cannot "decrypt" hash value produced by md5 in any way, at least for now. If you could, you would basically "break" it. MD5 is one of cryptographic hash functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: ***DO NOT USE MD5 FOR PASSWORDS!***

Comment: What can I use to ensure the security of the password in the database

Comment: @Noor http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't use md5 for password hashing. It's built for speed which makes it easier to attack. Use [bcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) instead. Also, you're not supposed to try to decrypt the password after it has been stored. See the examples on the bcrypt page for how to verify a password from user input. More [information](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) on how to store passwords safely.

jBcrypt is real simple to use too. Here's how you hash a password:

```
BCrypt.hashpw(password_from_user, BCrypt.gensalt());
```

And to verify it:

```
BCrypt.checkpw(password_from_user, hashed_password_from_database)
```

Comment: Can you explain why not use md5 or sha1 since that's a common way to do it?

Comment: The last link explains it all.

Comment: That only works until someone makes a fastbcrypt like what happened to the old Unix hash algorithm.

Comment: @JOTN that makes no sense. bcrypt is designed to be slow, and it's slowness is designed to be *adaptable*

Comment: The old Unix crypt was also designed to be slow for the same reason.  Someone then came up with fastcrypt that produced the same results much faster.  The left a lot of systems open to hacks because the crypted values could be accessed by any user.  Why protect them if they cannot be brute force attacked in a reasonable amount of time?

Answer (score 5):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) isn't an [encryption algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher) - it is a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). This is very different! You can store the hashed password in the database, but you cannot (in general) recover the password from the password's hash. **This is by design.**

In some cases it *is* possible to get the password back from the hash - for example if the password is a dictionary word it could be recovered using a [dictionary attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack). If the password is short enough and uses a characters from a limited range a [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack) or [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attack could recover the password. When you store a hashed password you should use a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and [key strengthening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_strengthening) (for example [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)) to make these attacks more difficult.

You should also be aware that MD5 is considered broken and it is recommended not to use it for new applications. There are better alternatives, for example [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

Comment: Agreed. In my opinion SHA-256 on salt+password should be enough for 99.9% of applications.

Answer (score 3):

1) There is no decrypt for MD5.
2) MD5 is old technology which is excellent for checking to see if two strings are the same.
3) MD5 is subject to dictionary assaults.
4) MD5 can be made more secure by using a salt.
5) We use MD5 for low level security because the hash can be easily duplicated across platforms. (C++, vb.net, VB6, C#, php ...)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use a hashing algorithm, you don't (can't) decrypt the password.  You hash the password and store the hash.  When the user provides their password in the future, you hash it with the same algorithm and compare the new hash with what you stored before.

You can use the [MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class in Java to hash a value.  Ref: [Get MD5 hash in a few lines of Java](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3686).

Edit: Also, I agree with the others who are saying not to use MD5 for this anymore.  It's an old algorithm that used to be common, but it's been attacked to the point of worthlessness (for passwords).  There are all sorts of resources online for MD5 reverse lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in postgres if you install the [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html) contrib module.

You can then encrypt passwords like this:

```
update ... set passwordhash = crypt('new password', gen_salt('md5'));
```

Of course you can't decrypt it at all!

As others have pointed out, this may be a bad idea, depending on what you are trying to do. I've been forced to use MD5 before because another application has demanded it, but you don't want to be broadcasting that hash to the world.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a DBMS specific solution with hibernate.  Portability between databases is a big advantage to using it.

Comment: @JOTN Thanks, that's interesting to know.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) encryption library to be quite useful.